# Event emitter loop not working in node-red function

Tags: node.js, node-red, azure-iot-hub

I am attempting to use a node-red function to read Azure IoT Hub messages using AMQP.   I have imported the azure-iothub module.

The code below connects ok and getFeedbackReceiver returns an AmqpReceiver object (I can see the object output to debug tab) which acts as an event emitter.  However, the emitter loop (msgReceiver.on) doesn't seem to run.   I don't even get a null output to debug tab.

Any help appreciated.

```
var azureamqp = global.get('azureamqp');

var iothub = azureamqp.Client.fromConnectionString(cnct);

try 
   {
         iothub.open(function()
         {
            node.send({type: "connection", payload: util.inspect(iothub)});
            node.status({ fill: "green", shape: "ring", text: "listening" }); 

            iothub.getFeedbackReceiver(function(err,msgReceiver)
                {
                    if (!err) 
                    {
                        node.send({type: "receiver", payload: util.inspect(msgReceiver)});
                        msgReceiver.on('message',function(message)
                            {
                                node.send({payload:message}); 
                            });                        
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        node.send({payload: err});
                    }
                });

            node.send({type: "streamend"}); 
            node.status({ fill: "red", shape: "ring", text: "disconnected" }); 
         });
   }
catch (err)
   {}
```

Comment: Tip: wrapping async function calls with a try-catch is not going to help in the way you are probably thinking it will.

Comment: Can you share how you send the cloud-to-device message and how the device responds to it as well? The feedback receiver will receive messages only if the device accepts or rejects it.

Comment: I am just trying to monitor all messages sent to Iot Hub by a given device, much like Azure IoT Hub Device Explorer does in the Data tab.   I agree that the naming of getFeedbackReceiver makes it seem like it is for responses to C2D messages but the very limited documentation says it should be used rather than the deprecated getReceiver and as far as I can tell from the code it should be more generic.   
Regardless, it doesn't explain why the code just continues on rather than waiting for events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I think I see what's happening thanks to the additional comments: First of, some reference docs about messaging with IoT Hub:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messaging

There are 2 types of messages that are sent through IoT Hub, depending on the direction in which they go:

- **Cloud to Device (C2D, or commands)**: these messages are sent by a cloud app to one or more devices. They are stored in a device-specific queue, and delivered to the device as soon as the device connects and starts listening for messages. Once received by the device, the device can choose to send feedback about these to IoT Hub. This feedback is received using the `azure-iothub.Client.getFeedbackReceiver()` API. I've added more about this at the end of the answer.
- **Device-to-Cloud (D2C, or telemetry)**: these messages are sent by the devices to the cloud application. These messages are stored in Event Hubs partitions and can be read from these partitions. This happens with the [Event Hubs SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-node)

From the question and the comments it looks like you're trying to receive D2C messages (telemetry) using the feedback API - and it's not working, because it's not meant to work that way. It's good feedback for (bad?) API design and lack of docs though.

#### How to receive messages sent by devices:

[This sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-node/blob/master/samples/javascript-eventhub-sample/simple_eventhubs_client.js) on github shows how to set up an Event Hubs client and can be used to listen to messages sent by devices to IoT Hub.[This command in iothub-explorer](https://github.com/Azure/iothub-explorer/blob/master/iothub-explorer-monitor-events.js) is also an easy reference.

Please find below a simple example:

```js
'use strict';
var EventHubClient = require('azure-event-hubs').Client;
var Promise = require('bluebird');

var connectionString = '[IoT Hub Connection String]';
var client = EventHubClient.fromConnectionString(connectionString);
var receiveAfterTime = Date.now() - 5000;

var printError = function (err) {
  console.error(err.message);
};

var printEvent = function (ehEvent) {
  console.log('Event Received: ');
  console.log(JSON.stringify(ehEvent.body));
  console.log('');
};

client.open()
      .then(client.getPartitionIds.bind(client))
      .then(function (partitionIds) {
        return Promise.map(partitionIds, function (partitionId) {
          return client.createReceiver('$Default', partitionId, { 'startAfterTime' : receiveAfterTime}).then(function(receiver) {
            receiver.on('errorReceived', printError);
            receiver.on('message', printEvent);
          });
        });
      }).catch(printError);
```

#### A little more about that code sample:

Basically, the Event Hubs client provide an AMQP connection can be used to open receivers on each partition of the Event Hub. Partitions are used to store messages sent by devices. Each partition gets its own receiver, and each receiver has a `message` event. Hence the need to open one receiver per partition to never miss any message from any devices. Here's a little bit more about Event Hubs and the nature of partitions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-what-is-event-hubs

#### More about C2D Feedback:

There are 3 types of feedback that a device can send about a C2D message:

- *accept* (or *complete*) means the message is taken care of by the device and the IoT Hub will remove this message from the device queue
- *reject* means that the device doesn't want this message (maybe because it's malformed, or irrelevant, that's up to you to device) and the IoT Hub will remove the message from the queue.
- *abandon* means that the device cannot "take care" of this message right now and wants IoT Hub to resend it later. The message remains in the queue.

*accept* and *reject* are both going to be observed using the `getFeedbackReceiver` API, as well as timeouts if the message is never received or is abandonned too many times.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed comment but it does not solve my problem.   It has however made me think about using the Event Hub API instead where at least there are examples of reading messages from the hub. It seems that as far as IoTHub is concerned, everyone wants to write to it but noone wants to read from it.  Maybe that is due to the excellent Stream Analytics tool which makes that job very easy.

Using an Event Hub example instead I hit the exact same issue. It skips over the EventEmitter.on calls and finishes immediately. I guess this something to do with the way node-red works.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand your question. My answer details how to read messages sent by devices to IoT hub. Just to rephrase or clarify: IoT Hub, under the hood, uses Event Hubs. in order to read messages sent by devices to IoT hub you have to connect to the event hubs-compatible endpoint associated with your IoT hub. You can do that by using the event hubs client and giving it the iothub connection string. That's what my answer is for. Maybe I don't understand what you mean by reading messages from IoT Hub? Can you rephrase the question then?

Comment: The issue is not connecting, it is staying connected.   The code completes immediately whereas I need it to continue to listen for messages.